# import react-banner in version 18 of react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In installed `react-banner` using `npm install react-banner --legacy-peer-deps` but when I try to import react banner into my Javascript using `import Banner from 'react-banner';` I get the following error:

```
info  - Linting and checking validity of types  
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data .ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/heroku-website/node_modules/react-banner/dist/react-banner.min.js:1:240)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1173:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:838:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at 34 (~/heroku-website/.next/server/pages/index.js:39:47)
    at __webpack_require__ (~/heroku-website/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (~/heroku-website/.next/server/pages/index.js:174:39)
```

Does anyone know what I have done wrong? Note that if I comment out the import statement, then the website compiles correctly.

Also, if I do not include `--legacy-peer-deps` then I cannot install `react-banner` (it expects version 16). Is there a newer version of `react-banner`?

I tried `--force` instead of `--legacy-peer-deps` (same result)

Comment: have you imported css styles with it: `import 'react-banner/dist/style.css'`?

Comment: Just tried this, it didn't change the error.